# How to use addContentView?

Tags: android, statusbar, android-windowmanager

I want to Hide the status bar for my tablets, adding a transparent tape to the status bar that locks the touch event, but my problem is that the bar displayed on the top and not down on the status bar. how do to change its position.

```
View disableStatusBar = new View(this);
            disableStatusBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

            WindowManager.LayoutParams handleParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  50,
                // This allows the view to be displayed over the status bar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,//or other type_system make same
                // this is to keep button presses going to the background window
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE |
                // this is to enable the notification to recieve touch events
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL |
                // Draws over status bar
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR_PANEL,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

            handleParams.gravity = Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;
            getWindow().addContentView(disableStatusBar, handleParams);
```

Comment: handleParams.gravity = Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.BOTTOM;

Comment: I tried this, but it is all the time in the same place.

Comment: @Zizou.sorry. no idea...